# How can i get jade template to compile automatically in visual studio on save operation?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, pug, grunt-contrib-jade

Could anyone post some basic steps on how to get *.html files to compile to *.jade files on file change / save operation in Visual Studio?

I have installed nodetools, web essentials. Syntax highlighting seems to work, but creating a .jade file does nothing. I think there is a missing step somewhere.

Do I have to use something like grunt-contrib-jade with a task?

Comment: Yes, grunt or gulp task to watch your files and compile when changed is what you need. But if you use some view engine in your app you don't need to compile it at all. I mean I use express with jade view engine and it is compiled on demand.

Comment: I am using angularjs not sure if i can integrate it into the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015: After fiddling around a lot the answer i have is as follows:

1. Install node
2. Install NodeTools for visual studio
3. Run: npm install jade (install jade)
4. Run: npm install -g grunt-cli (install grunt)
5. Run: npm install bower
6. Create the below package.json file

**Package.json : as follows**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jade": "0.15.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.6.1"  
  }
}
```

**7) Create the following grunt.js file**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        jade: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    data: {
                        debug: true,
                        timestamp: "<%= new Date().getTime() %>"
                    }
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    src: '**/*.jade', 
                    ext : '.html'
                }]
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
            },
            build: {
                src: 'Scripts/bootstrap.js',
                dest: 'Scripts/build/bootstrap.min.js'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            jade: {
                files: '**/*.jade',
                tasks: ['jade:watch'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
        }
    });



    grunt.event.on('watch', function (action, filepath) {
        if (filepath.indexOf('.jade') === -1) return;
        var file = {};
        var destfile = filepath.replace('.jade', '.html');
        file[destfile] = filepath
        grunt.config('jade.watch.files', file);
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jade');
    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
};
```

Open Task Explorer and then make sure you add/bind the task "watch" to project open.

Comment: how to bind task in vscode while project open is their any link or tutorial?